# How to display progress dialog with media player ?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, progressdialog

There is a problem in the following media player that plays the audio stream when you press play if the stream is not available there is no any response from the program, How can I solve this issue, try to make progress dialog, but the solution does not work, maybe I did something wrong, but when you click on the progress bar appears first and then immediately disappears without waiting to start playback of music.

setDataSource filed in advance a broken link, nothing has changed.

Code media player with progress dialog:

```
private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,Void>{
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {   
            preload();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            MPplay();
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);               

        }
    }

public void preload() {
    releaseMP();
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        if(pdaStream.isChecked()){
            Main_stream = "http://145.255.233.204:58000/radio_pda";             
        }else{
            Main_stream = "http://145.255.233.204:58000/radio";
        }
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(Main_stream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "prepareAsync");
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();;
   }

public void MPplay(){
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {  
        @Override  
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
        }  
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see when a video is ready for playback, use this callback. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener.html

```
onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
//Called when the media file is ready for playback.
```

If you would like to see when a video is 100% buffered, use this callback: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener.html

```
public abstract void onBufferingUpdate (MediaPlayer mp, int percent)
```

Comment: Thanks I realized my mistake, I did not see a progress bar in the place